# stackoverflowerror null

Tags: java

The error i am having here is a infinite or near infinite loop in my method calls and class's creating other class's constructors.  What my program is trying to do is semi-randomly generate survey results based off actual statistics.  I would highly appreciate not only some insight in whats going wrong here.  But some advice and pointers on how to prevent this from happening and ways to analyze the error messages by myself.  I get how some of the work but like i stated below i am new to programming im a freshman in college so programming is new to me.  Thanks in advance and sorry for my previous post, thought i would take the time to give you guys an appropriate one.

Im new to programming this is my 2nd project ive done on my own so im sorry if its not the best.

This is my Test class:

```
 public Tester()
{
    randomGenerator = new Random();
    probability = new Probability();
    stats = new Statistics();
    double chance = randomGenerator.nextDouble();
    double gender = probability.getProbabilityOfMale();
    if(chance > gender)
    {
        male = false;
        stats.incrementFemale();
    }else{
        male = true;
        stats.incrementMale();
    }
    age = randomGenerator.nextInt(49)+16;
    int range = stats.getNumberOfQuestion();
    for(int i=0;i<range;i++)
    {
       probabilities = probability.probOfAnswer(i);
       answers = probability.getAnswers(i);
       chance = randomGenerator.nextDouble();
       int size = probabilities.size();
       for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
       {
         double qTemp = chance - probabilities.get(j);
         if(qTemp <= 0.0)
         {
             Answer aTemp = answers.get(j);
             aTemp.incrementCounter();
             answers.set(j,aTemp);
          }
       }
    }
}
```

Statistics class:

```
 public ArrayList<Answer> getAnswers(int index)
{
    temp = survey.getAnswers(index);
    return temp;
}

public int getMale()
{
    return male;
}

public int getFemale()
{
    return female;
}

public int getNumberOfQuestion()
{
    return numberOfQuestion;
}

public void incrementNumberOfQuestion()
{
    numberOfQuestion++;
}

public void incrementMale()
{
    male++;
}

public void incrementFemale()
{
    female++;
}
```

and probability class:

```
 public Probability()
{
    stats = new Statistics();
    probOfAnswer = new ArrayList<Double>(0);
}

public ArrayList<Double> probOfAnswer(int index)
{               
    temp = stats.getAnswers(index);
    int size = temp.size();
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        aTemp = temp.get(i);
        for(int j=0;j<size;j++)
        {
            Answer aTemp = temp.get(j);
            sum += (double)aTemp.getCounter(); 
        }
        double number = (double)aTemp.getCounter();
        probOfAnswer.add(number/sum);
        sum = 0;

    }
    return probOfAnswer;
}

public ArrayList<Answer> getAnswers(int index)
{
    temp = stats.getAnswers(index);
    return temp;
}

public ArrayList<Double> getProbofAnswer()
{
    return probOfAnswer;
}

public void probabilityOfMale()
{        
    double male = (double)stats.getMale();
    double female = (double)stats.getFemale();
    probabilityOfMale = male / (male + female);
}

public double getProbabilityOfMale()
{
    return probabilityOfMale;
}
```

These are the only real important parts where the loop exsists the rest of the code is not needed to be uploaded.

Im having difficulty uploading my error message on this site its not accepting it as code in the code insert, then it wont let me submit the message afterwards so im going to upload the code elseware and link it.

http://forum.overdosed.net/index.php/topic/56608-this-is-unimportant/

But i dont know how long that forum will let me keep that post there ><

Comment: You haven't shown us the constructor of `Statistics`, which is where I suspect the problem is.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
at Question.<init>(Question.java:17)
at Survey.addQuestion(Survey.java:23)
at Statistics.<init>(Statistics.java:52)
at Question.<init>(Question.java:17)
at Survey.addQuestion(Survey.java:23)
at Statistics.<init>(Statistics.java:52)
at Probability.<init>(Probability.java:19)
```

You need to check why Question is creating Statistics object and again Statistics is trying to create Question object leading to infinite recursion. As the line numbers are given you can take a look at corresponding lines.

Comment: thanks found and fixed the issue, when i go back to college im going to ask my professors tips on reading error messages.  I still cant really sit down and understand how you figured out what you figured out.  I mean i understand some of it, just not enough to really understand whats being said.

Comment: @PatrickMurphy There is no trick in reading the stack trace. If function A calls B and you have an exception in B then the point where error occured in B will be at top, followed by place in A where B was called and so on. So if you are not able to figure out error at first point you can go deeper and try to find the cause.

Answer (score 2):

Judging by the stack trace, the problem lies in three parts which you haven't shown us - the `Question` and `Statistics` constructors and the `Survey.addQuestion` method:

From the stack trace:

```
at Survey.addQuestion(Survey.java:23)
at Statistics.<init>(Statistics.java:52)
at Question.<init>(Question.java:17)
at Survey.addQuestion(Survey.java:23)
at Statistics.<init>(Statistics.java:52)
at Question.<init>(Question.java:17)
```

So your `Question` constructor is calling the `Statistics` constructor. But the `Statistics` constructor is then calling `Survey.addQuestion`, which is in turn calling the `Question` constructor.

It feels to me like there's *much* more construction going on than is really useful. Why would a `Statistics` constructor need to add anything to a survey? I wouldn't expect a `Statistics` class to even *know* about surveys and questions.

It's entirely possible that a lot of this can be fixed by passing a reference to an *existing* object to the constructors - so the `Probability` constructor may be better *taking* a `Statistics` reference in its constructor and using that for its `stats` field than creating a new `Statistics` object itself. It's hard to say without knowing what these classes are really meant to represent though... which may be part of the problem. Do you have a firm grasp of what the responsibility of each class is? Think about that carefully before making any code changes.

Answer (score 0):

We don't have the relevant source code, but the error message says what's wrong:

1. Tester creates a Probability
2. Probability constructor creates a Statistics
3. Statistics constructor calls Survey.addQuestion()
4. addQuestion() creates a Question
5. Question creates a Statistics (goto 3 and loop infinitely)

I think you should probably pass objects around rather than creating them each time.